# Using Angular 2 Multiselect dropdown

Tags: angular

I've finally managed to load the [softsimon angular-2-multiselect-dropdown](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect).
How do i get the selected options ?

I'm using softsimon angular-2-multiselect-dropdown v 0.4.0

**Edit: **

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="ArrayObject" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" (onModelChange)="dummy"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

ArrayObject is :

```
    for(let x = 0; x < this.productArray.length ; x++ ){
        let temp={id : x , name : this.productArray[x]};
        this.ArrayObject[x]=temp;
    }
```

Output asked :

```
[ { "id": 0, "name": "redBox" }, { "id": 1, "name": "orangeBox" } ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Why are you not just using `this.ArrayObject.push({id : x , name : this.productArray[x]});`. What do you get if you add `<div>{{ArrayObject | json}}</div>` to your page? Can you please add this output to your question as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i'll make the changes you've suggested . i have added the output you asked .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `ngModel` to the `ss-multiselect-dropdown` like this:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown 
   [options]="ArrayObject" 
   [texts]="myTexts" 
   [settings]="mySettings" 
   (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
   [ngModel]="selectedTexts"
></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

You have to change your component which is using this multiselect to something like this:

```
export class TextSelectorComponent {

   public selectedTexts: any[] = [];

   public onChange(): void {
      console.log(this.selectedTexts);
   }

}
```

After a change is triggered, the `ngModel` will then contain the selected values inside the `selectedTexts` variable.

Comment: I added [(ngModel)] to the html tag @PierreDuc, and i got an error   as ngModel is not a nown property of ss-multiselect-dropdown. Further ,i removed [(ngModel)] and added a debugger point on line containing onChange() , the function is not executed .

Comment: Have you added the angular FormModule to your imports ? I've also updated my answer to only use the `[]` notation and not the `[()]`. You can try that as well. This is because there is already a ngModelChange listener

Comment: Now it is working . Thank you :) . I had not imported the FormsModule . I have aapplied the changes on ngModel .

Comment: Can I then ignore [options]="ArrayObject" in <ss-multiselect-dropdown ?

Comment: The first value of the selection is `""`. Anyone faced this?